# Does Samsung SL-M2070 work with ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, samsung, scanner

I'm planning to buy a Samsung SL-M2070 Multifunction Priter. Can you reinforce me that this device works with ubuntu 14.04? In particular to the scanner functionality.

Thank you,

Comment: There is a Linux driver for printing and scanning [here](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_NL&CttFileID=6342866&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=SL-M2070&VPath=DR/201512/20151210091120064/uld_v1.00.37_00.99.tar.gz), supplied by Samsung, which means that it *very probably*  will work with Ubuntu 14.04. However, not all scanning programs are bug-free.

Comment: Hi Jos,
Thanks for the quick reply. I'll make more make more inquiries before buying it. and will update this question with my decision.
My other option is XEROX WorkCentre 3025V_BI. I might buy this one instead...

Answer (score 1):

I bought the device. I can confirm that it fully works with ubuntu 14.04. I installed the driver from Samsung's website. Scanning is OK with ubuntu's default scanner software, so is printing. This is a good budget device.